# how to make cypress wait for a async search with multiple result complete without causing the test to fail

Tags: testing, cypress, end-to-end

I have a typical search where the user types some text in an input, async work is done and a table with the results is properly updated.

I have tests that must wait for this search step and then assert business rules regarding the results, like if the table records are eligible for edit.

Every time I ran a complete test battery (something like 80 test files), one or two of the tests involving that search inevitably fail. But if immediately after that, I run the same test alone, the test passes. It's excruciating and makes e2e testing in CI/CD pointless for the project.

I've read the Cypress documentation about flaky tests and searched questions in StackOverflow and GitHub with only complete failure. It's a drama.

Here is one of the tests:

```js
import { searchList } from '../helpers';
import { createFluxoIniciado, randomFluxoNome } from './common';
import { fluxoSelectors } from './selectors';

describe('fluxos finish', () => {
  it('can manually finish a fluxo INICIADO', () => {
   // feed data to be searched
    const fluxoNome = randomFluxoNome();
    createFluxoIniciado({ fluxoNome });

    // search
    searchList(fluxoNome);

    // do something with search results
    fluxoSelectors.fluxos.view().click();
    fluxoSelectors.finish().click();
    fluxoSelectors.confirm().click();

   // serach again
    searchList(fluxoNome);
    cy.contains('FINALIZADO');
  });
});
```

The code in `searchList` is where trouble emerge sometimes. It uses the callback strategy recommended [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability#Use-should-with-a-callback). The code attempts to cause retries if not all rows have the searched text.

```js
export function searchList (text) {
  cy.get('#searchText')
    .scrollIntoView()
    .type(text)
    .blur();

  cy.get('tbody tr').should($trs => {
    $trs.each((i, $tr) => {
      expect($tr).to.contain(text);
    });
  }, { timeout: 15000 });
}
```

Here is an example of a test failure inside a run all test execution:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obviously caused by the async fetch between `.blur()` and testing the rows.

You are correctly trying to use Cypress retry with `.should(callback)`, but if the callback is complex or there are multiple steps it may not retry the element that is changing (the table rows).

Ideally you want to keep the `cy.get(...).should(...)` as simple as possible, and start by testing that the table loading has completed.

```js
// wait for expected number of rows
cy.get('tbody tr', {timeout: 15000}).should('have.length', 5)  

cy.get('tbody tr').each($tr => {
  expect($tr).to.contain(text);
})
```

But you have a randomizer there, so maybe it's not possible to test explicitly the row count.

Another approach, test the whole table for `text` (`.contains()` checks child text also)

```js
// wait for text to appear somewhere
cy.get('tbody tr', {timeout: 15000}).should('contain', text)  

cy.get('tbody tr').each($tr => {
  expect($tr).to.contain(text);
})
```

You can also add an intercept between start and end of api call

```js
export function searchList (text) {

  cy.intercept('search/api/endpoint').as('search')

  cy.get('#searchText')
    .scrollIntoView()
    .type(text)
    .blur();

  cy.wait('@search')   // wait for api response

  cy.get('tbody tr', {timeout: 15000}).should('contain', text) 

  cy.get('tbody tr').each($tr => {
    expect($tr).to.contain(text);
  })
}
```

---

I just noticed you have the `{timeout}` option on `.should()`, but that's the wrong place,
see [Timeouts](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Timeouts)

> ```js
> cy.get('input', { timeout: 10000 }).should('have.value', '10')
> // timeout here will be passed down to the '.should()'
> // and it will retry for up to 10 secs
> ```

This may be successful

```js
cy.get('tbody tr', { timeout: 15000 })
  .should($trs => {
    $trs.each((i, $tr) => {
      expect($tr).to.contain(text);
    });
  })
```

Comment: about the first suggestion, you are right, the data used during tests is random and that is a restriction. row count after search is, like you said, unpredictable.

Comment: the third one couldn't also be used, i think. because the async work has more pieces than the api server call. sometimes, for example, the network request is not even done due to a cache strategy at client side. the only reliable signal that the search is "done" is a correct list of results shown to the user in the table.

Comment: will check the second suggestion and return. thank you for your fast answer.

Comment: You might also want to incorporate the ideas here [How to run the same test again and again to confirm it is flake-free](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/burning-tests/)

Comment: hi mihi. i tried the second approach and it also didn't work. the "should contain" assertion goes fine but the immediate command after that fails. i recalled later, this was the first approach i tried. after the search, the test (sometimes) fails when it attempts to get a button in the table row to edit the record. cypress complains the element is detached or not available. if i remember correctly, it is a side effect of using reactive frameworks like vue. i think i will just put an arbitrary wait after the search :( -- but thanks a lot again.

Comment: also tks for the article recommendation. it is a very useful plugin.